# Compiler errors using pip to install javabridge

Tags: python, visual-studio, compiler-errors, pip, environment-variables

I am running Windows 10, Python 3.6.5, Visual Studio 2017, MinGW current version and am having trouble installing javabridge, a python package with dependencies: JDK, NumPy, Python 2.7 or above, and a C compiler.

My first error was due to the fact that the file cl.exe could not be located. After doing some research I found this file was in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

Adding this directory to the environment variable 'Path' solved this issue. Now I am running into the issue that 'io.h' cannot be found.

```
 Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have tried downloading and running setup.py install, but the same error occurs.

My question is: 
How can I edit my environment variables to include io.h and all other directories used by C compiler from pip? If there are other workarounds I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't run the appropriate `vcvars`  batch file (or used the Start Menu item that opens a new console with it automatically taken care of for you).

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: I think [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_10.0_standalone:_Windows_SDK_7.1_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ia64.29) has the up-to-date instructions for every combination of Windows, Python, and compiler.

Comment: I downloaded the Build Tools again and I ran the same commands from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and recieved this error:  fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86', but I am sure I downloaded the right Visual Studio (x64) for my 64-bit computer.

Comment: You're obviously mixing 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (x86_64, sometimes called x64) tools. If you installed 32-bit Python, you need a 32-bit compiler; if you installed 64-bit Python, you need a 64-bit compiler. This is explained in the introduction to the wiki page.

Comment: Installing Build Tools installs both 32-bit and 64-bit. I solved my problem by opening the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt that comes with Visual Studio's Build Tools and running pip javabridge. Before I was using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, which uses 32-bit compilers?

Comment: Microsoft changes the names of the different "command prompt" options with each version, so I can't keep track of them. But yes, I guess "Developer Command Prompt" is 32-bit x86 for some reason, and "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" definitely should be 64-bit  x64, so that makes sense.